# Weird nginx caching

Tags: caching, nginx, vagrant, puphpet

I'm trying to set up a development server with [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/), which is essentially just a pre-made build of Vagrant with PHP, Nginx and a few other things pre-installed.

I'm having a weird caching issue with my .css files.

[image]

When I access my .css file directly at my dev URL, it shows part of the file. This is the file as it was originally before I started editing it. You will notice from my screenshot that I've deleted the entire contents of the file and replaced it with the numbers "12345". When I refresh the .css file in my browser, I see the first 5 characters of the *old* file. Adding an extra character restores an additional character from the old file.

Restarting nginx does not clear the cache. Ctrl+F5 does not clear the cache. Checking the file contents from `vagrant ssh`:

```
[08:11 PM]-[vagrant@precise64]-[/var/www/public/css]-[hg default] B
B$ cat main.css
12345
```

I can see the file is up to date. The file it's partially displaying simply does not exist. My best guess is it's reading the length of the file on disk, and then pulling the actual contents from memory.

The built-in PHP 5.4 development server does not have this problem, so I'm pretty sure Nginx is the culprit.

How can I get Nginx to behave in a sane fashion?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it's [this know VirtualBox bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819) with the `sendfile` system call.

Try disabling sendfile in nginx config:

```
sendfile off;
```

(In apache `EnableSendfile off`)